# How update property with single quotes on ORMLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

When I try update a object with a property that contains single quote, happens error type: near "Agua": syntax error

The value of property is: "D'Agua"

But the orm lite make the sql with single quote as example:

```
UPDATE 'table' SET 'value' = 'D'Agua'
```

Result of code:

```
UpdateBuilder<Table, Integer> updateBuilder = tableDAO.updateBuilder();
try {
  updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("value", tableDTO.getDescricao());
  updateBuilder.update();
} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please show your code that results in this SQL command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I try update a object with a property that contains single quote, happens error type: near "Agua": syntax error

This is a FAQ.  Anytime you might have special characters in your statements, you should leverage the SQL `?` arguments.  With [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/), you use the `SelectArg` class.  Sort of an unfortunate name given that its an update.

```
SelectArg selectArg = new SelectArg(tableDTO.getDescricao());
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("value", selectArg);
updateBuilder.update();
```

This will result in the SQL:

```
UPDATE 'table' SET 'value' = ?
```

Then the string `"D'Agua"` will be passed into the update statement as an argument.

More on this via a search for ["quotes in queries" in the online docs](http://ormlite.com/docs/quotes-in-queries).